# How to configure samba not to share or not to disply shares?

Tags: samba, smb

How can I configure samba so that I can connect to a WORKGROUP with boxes with diffeerent op systems but not to share or hide the shares from other boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Install **Samba Server Configuration** with `sudo apt-get install system-config-samba`. From there you edit each of the samba shares you have between your computers, choose which users are allowed to acess the folders, and whether the shares are "visible" or "writable".

Comment: But that is for a server, right? I just want to be a desktop that when connects to a network with samba, can see the samba-shares but doesn't want to share anything or maybe, one day, doesn't want to show its shares. Is there another solution?

Comment: **Samba Server Configuration** lets you configure everything about the ways samba works in your computer, not only servers. If you have other computers sharing folders in you network, they will also show up, and you can choose whether to set them as "visible" or "writable". Give it a try :)